# Change column width of cventry in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

It seems that the cventry in moderncv class is limited to 89 char per line. Is it possible to change it?

Here is the code I've used, in LyX. I'm afraid I don't know what the version of the moderncv is.

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.0.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{moderncv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{pifont}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\moderncvtheme[red]{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm,twoside]{geometry}
%\newgeometry{margin=1cm,includefoot}
\firstname{Nice}
\familyname{Nic}
\title{whatever}
\address{blablae}{blabla}
\mobile{080008000}
\email{blablablablablabla@blabla.com}
\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{\textbullet}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\ding{43}}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace*{-2cm}


\section{Profile}

Abilities forfeited situation extremely my to he resembled. Old had
conviction discretion understood put principles you. Match means keeps
round one her quick. She forming two comfort invited. Yet she income
effect edward. Entire desire way design few. Mrs sentiments led solicitude
estimating friendship fat. Meant those event is weeks state it to
or. Boy but has folly charm there its. Its fact ten spot drew. 


\section{Key Skills}


\cventry{Programming}{Python, Ruby, Bash Shell, VBA}{}{}{}{}


\cventry{Databases}{Oracle SQL, PL/SQL}{}{}{}{}


\cventry{Databases}{Oracle SQL, PL/SQL}{}{}{}{}


\section{Employment History}


\cventry{Sep. 2011 --\\
Present}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}{}{}{}{Advice me cousin an spring
of needed. Tell use paid law ever yet new. Meant to learn of vexed
if style allow he there. Tiled man stand tears ten joy there terms
any widen. Procuring continued suspicion its ten. Pursuit brother
are had fifteen distant has. Early had add equal china quiet visit.
Appear an manner as no limits either praise in. In in written on charmed
justice is amiable farther besides. Law insensible middletons unsatiable
for apartments boy delightful unreserved.}


\subsection{Some of the day-to-day responsibilities includes:}


\cvlistitem{Improve ashamed married expense bed her comfort pursuit mrs. }


\cvlistitem{Four time took ye your as fail lady. Up greatest am exertion or marianne.
Shy occasional terminated insensible and inhabiting gay. So know do
fond to half on. Now who promise was justice new winding. In finished
on he speaking suitable advanced if. }


\cvlistitem{Boy happiness sportsmen say prevailed offending concealed nor was
provision. Provided so as doubtful on striking required. Waiting we
to compass assured. }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22):

The total width of `\cventry` depends on the width of your page. You can change that one by using the `geometry` package:

```
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
```

Assuming you are using the "classic" style variant, if you want to change the width of the left column, you should use (for a width of `5cm` as an example):

```
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{5cm}
```

Comment: looks like it just padded more or less space in the entry but the column width didn't change.

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to illustrate the issue, as it is hard to help you otherwise. Please also indicate which version of `moderncv` you are using.

Comment: Yes, I've edited my post - thank you in advance.

Comment: @Dean The "M" of MWE stands for "Minimal". Please try to make your code as short as possible (check the link of my previous comment to understand why we require it here and how it benefits you too). Please also clarify what the issue is; my answer above enables you both to enlarge the total width of the page (and hence of `\cventry`) and to specifically change the width of the left column. I don't understand what you tried and what you mean when you say "it just padded more or less space"...

Comment: Hi Xavier, \cventry indeed changes the left column, is it possible to change the width of right column?

Comment: @Dean I still don't get your issue. The first line of code of my answer changes the total width of the text, hence also (and mostly) the width of the right column...

Comment: If you want to change the width of the other column, you can also directly change `\maincolumnwidth`.

Comment: NB: This has to be done *after* the `\moderncvstyle` command.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, try to play around with 
`\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{}` a little. It's changing the width of the left 'column' and therefor also effecting the right one.

Comment: This seems to be a subset of Xavier's answer and less precise.  New answers should provide alternative approaches.  Good answers should also contain complete working code, rather than code snippets.